# Google Now intercepts `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` (Strange)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-now

My problem is a bit weird, but I'll try to be specific.
This is my code.

```
if(l.contains("search yahoo")||l.contains("yahoo search")&& !l.contains("search yahoo search"))
                    {
                        String query = l;
                        query = query.replace("search", "");
                        query = query.replace("yahoo", "");
                        String url = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + query;
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    if(l.contains("search bing")||l.contains("bing search")&& !l.contains("search bing search"))
                    {
                        String query = l;
                        query = query.replace("search", "");
                        query = query.replace("bing", "");
                        String url = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + query + "&go=Submit&qs=ds&form=QBLH";
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        String v2txt = txt2SpeechWords.get(0);

                        v2txt = v2txt.replace("search", "");

                        txt2Speech.speak("searching " + v2txt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                        Intent search = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                        search.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, v2txt);
                        startActivity(search);
                    }
```

In the part where my program decides whether it should search Yahoo! or Bing for Bing it works perfectly.
But for Yahoo! It opens in the web browser but when I hit the back button on my device it opens Google Now with the query except for the words Yahoo & Search as I have replaced them in the code.

Why does this happen? I am pretty sure the problem occurs after it has decided which search engine to use as in Google Now it removes the word Yahoo!

Why is `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` Intercepted by Google Now for the Yahoo! Part while this does not occur in the Bing part. It is pretty ironic since I pretty much copied the Yahoo! Code into notepad, replaced Yahoo as Bing & Pasted it in Android Studio.

Comment: Have you encoded the query to URL encoding (eg. "my big dog" would be "my+big+dog")? I believe there's a Java class (URLEncode?) to do that. It might not solve your original problem, but it sure will solve future problems.

Comment: @kkirigaya I'll try this and let you know soon. Also thanks for the reply

Comment: @kkirigaya also the only main differences in the 2 parts are that 'Yahoo' is replaced as bing but I know the `if` statement works. The second is that the 2 `url`'s are different. So maybe if I add in the yahoo part an `+ ""` would it work. I am not sure. However I will definitely try your suggestion and my idea and let you know soon. Thanks.

Comment: Oh My Gods! I made the most dumbest mistake. In the yahoo part it is if and in bing it is if as well. Bing's if statement must be made `else if`. Also my question has a mistake. In google now it does not replace Yahoo! therefore the `if` statement is wrong. I just noticed. Sorry is the question had a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the most dumbest mistake. In the yahoo part it is `if` and in bing it is `if` as well. Bing's `if` statement must be made `else if`. Also my question has a mistake. In google now it does not replace Yahoo! therefore the `if` statement is wrong. I just noticed. Sorry for that.

Correct Code:

```
if(l.contains("search yahoo")||l.contains("yahoo search")&& !l.contains("search yahoo search"))
                {
                    String query = l;
                    query = query.replace("search", "");
                    query = query.replace("yahoo", "");
                    String url = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + query;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(l.contains("search bing")||l.contains("bing search")&& !l.contains("search bing search"))
                {
                    String query = l;
                    query = query.replace("search", "");
                    query = query.replace("bing", "");
                    String url = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + query + "&go=Submit&qs=ds&form=QBLH";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else {
                    String v2txt = txt2SpeechWords.get(0);

                    v2txt = v2txt.replace("search", "");

                    txt2Speech.speak("searching " + v2txt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                    Intent search = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                    search.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, v2txt);
                    startActivity(search);
                }
```